# How to filter dateframe by end of business month ('BM') using datetime?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, data-science

I'm trying to look at the adjusted close stock values of a particular stock at the end of the month. I was able to get a dataframe of dates and adjclose values, but I can't seem to be able to filter that dataframe to include only dates that are end of month and their corresponding adj close value.

```
 apple_adjclose = apple_stock[['date','adjclose']]
```

this is the dataframe which includes dates for 2 years in the following format YYYY-MM-DD, and adjclose has float values. Help is really appreciated!

[Sample picture of input and output I'm getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZL2u.png)
(still haven't figured out how to put tables in my questions :)

[Other attempt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XR1Wu.png)

[Attempt 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAtPl.png)

[Solved here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3B6UK.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Add some sample data and expected output.

Comment: @min2bro Thanks! I just added a picture of my input and output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

converted date from object to datetime then used .asfreq() to get what I needed. Solution can be found here: 
[Solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKIZl.png)

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a dataframe like this with two columns,

```
dates = pd.date_range('01/01/2016', '12/31/2017')
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':dates,'adjclose':np.random.randint(100,200, len(dates))})
```

You can create an instance of offsets BMonthEnd to get the dates with MonthEnd freq and slice of the dataframe

```
df.loc[df.date.isin(df.date + pd.offsets.BMonthEnd(1))]


   adjclose date
28  128     2016-01-29
59  193     2016-02-29
90  167     2016-03-31
119 185     2016-04-29
151 133     2016-05-31
181 184     2016-06-30
```

Comment: I just added a picture of my attempt, the dateframe I have has dates as non-null objects. I tried apple_adjclose.loc[apple_adjclose.date.isin(apple_adjclose.date + pd.offsets.BMonthEnd(1))] but it didn't seem to work. GotTypeError: Argument 'other' has incorrect type (expected datetime.datetime, got str)

Comment: Can you also print apple_stock.dtypes

Comment: added screenshot

Comment: Your date column is of type object, not datetime. First convert it using df[‘date’] = pd.to_datetime(df[‘date’])

Comment: got it,it works.. but how does the offset work exactly? So basically we are accessing the date within the df using the .loc and df.date then what is happening, how does the offset work to output the end of months records?

Comment: Month end offset returns the last date of the month of each date and you slice your dataframe using that. You can print the df.date + pd.offsets.BMonthEnd(1) to see the output. I am on phone so can’t update the post right now

Comment: Actually, it worked in the sense that it produced output but it is missing feb and march end of month data. I attached screenshot for reference as third attempt.